# Как найти среди N точек с целочисленными координатами пару самых ближних и пару самых дальних друг от друга точек?

Tags: java

**Данные задачи**

На плоскости заданы N точек с целочисленными координатами. Требуется найти среди них пару самых ближних и пару самых дальних друг от друга точек.

**Входные данные**

Первая строка входного файла INPUT.TXT содержит целое число N (2 ≤ N ≤ 1000) – количество точек. Далее следует N строк пар целых чисел (X<sub>i</sub>,Y<sub>i</sub>), описывающих координаты первой, второй и т.д. точек соответственно (-10<sup>9</sup> ≤ X<sub>i</sub>,Y<sub>i</sub> ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>).

**Выходные данные**

В первой строке выходного файла OUTPUT.TXT выведите через пробел номера пары ближних друг к другу точек. Во второй строке выведите номера пары дальних друг от друга точек. В случае неоднозначности определения ответа выведите любой.

Мое решение прошло 10 тестов из 20:

```
package task1123;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Task1123 {
    public static class point {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        
        public point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

        }
    }

    public static double dist(point a,point b) {
        return Math.sqrt((a.x - b.x)*(a.x - b.x)+(a.y - b.y)*(a.y - b.y));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
        point a[] = new point[1000];
        int n, p = 0, q = 1, r = 0,s = 1;
        double c = 0, mn, mx;
        n = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = new point(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
        }
        mn = dist(a[0],a[1]);
        mx = mn;
        for(int i = 0;i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                c = dist(a[i],a[j]);
                if(c < mn){
                    mn=c;
                    p=i;
                    q=j;
                }
                else if(c > mx){
                    mx=c;
                    r=i;
                    s=j;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println((p + 1) + " " + (q + 1));
        System.out.println((r + 1) + " " + (s + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: `return Math.sqrt(...)` - `sqrt` тут не нужно, вы можете сравнимать квадраты расстояний как целые числа, чтобы не зависеть от проблем с точностью. `else if(c > mx){` -  `else` тут не нужно, хлтя это и не критично, но без else читать код будет легче.

Comment: `point a[] = new point[1000];` вы же знаете количество точек (n) - зачем создавать сразу большой массив? Нет в этом смысла

Comment: @tym32167, убрал корень и else, все также 10 тестов.

Comment: @tym32167, с else лучше - нечего просто так бесполезные условия проверять.

Comment: @Qwertiy по производительности будет то же самое, по читаемости без else полегче будет. Хотя согласен, это больше вкусовщина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> (a.x - b.x)*(a.x - b.x)+(a.y - b.y)*(a.y - b.y)
> ```

2*(2*10<sup>9</sup>)<sup>2</sup> - используй `long`, а не `int`. И выкинь квадратный корень.

Comment: черт, а я то удивился, причем тут 109, а это 10^9 `-109 ≤ Xi,Yi ≤ 109`

Comment: @0xdb, я не согласен, что это улучшение.

Comment: @Qwertiy А что это, ухудшение?

Comment: @0xdb, стилистика ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy И чем хуже? Безличная форма высказываний, т.е. ориентация на будущих читателей. Или есть подозрение, что их не будет?

Comment: @0xdb, безличная - это "надо использовать". А оба варианта "используй" и "используйте" безличными не являются.

Comment: Имел ввиду форму обращения к не конкретному лицу. А с  "надо использовать" было бы ещё лучше.